# RandomVariate with ProbabilityDistribution performs well in 10.0, but not in later versions

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, singularity

I have a custom probability distribution function and I want to generate numbers according to this PDF. Interestingly enough, this works without trouble on my MacBook with Mathematica 10.0, but when I try to run the exact same notebook on a Linux machine having later Mathematica versions, the execution takes orders of magnitude longer and even tends to crash the kernel.

An example of a PDF that shows up in my computations is the following:

[image: plot of probability distribution function]

It blows up for t=0,1,2. However, on my Macbook this does not cause any problems. If I cut off the pdf at a certain maximum value, the linux implementation also seems to work, so I suspect these singularities to cause the issue. What could be the reason for this discrepancy between different operating systems?

<del>I'm running Mathematica 10.0.2 on the MacBook, and tried several different versions on the Linux machine, including 9.0, 10.3 and 11.0, so I don't expect this to cause the problem.</del> The problem was confirmed to be due to the version difference, not the operating system difference (see comments).

The reason I didn't provide code initially is that the pdf is generated through a complicated process that will not illustrate the problem. However, to provide a little more detail, here is an example of a typical pdf:

```
pdf = 1. (1/(2 \[Pi]) \[Sqrt](0.0332814 (12. Cos[
            0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))] - 
          1. Sqrt[-80. + 
            144. Cos[0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))]^2])^2 + 
       0.015625 (17.5135 Sin[0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))] - (
          210.162 Cos[0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))] Sin[
            0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))])/
          Sqrt[-80. + 
           144. Cos[0.5 (1.45946 - 2.91891 (-1 + t))]^2])^2) UnitStep[
     2 - t] UnitStep[-1. + t] + (1/(
   2 \[Pi]))\[Sqrt](0.0332814 (12. Cos[0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)] + 
          Sqrt[-80. + 144. Cos[0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)]^2])^2 + 
       0.015625 (-17.5135 Sin[0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)] - (
          210.162 Cos[0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)] Sin[
            0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)])/
          Sqrt[-80. + 
           144. Cos[0.5 (-1.45946 + 2.91891 t)]^2])^2) UnitStep[
     1 - t] UnitStep[t])
```

The pdfs are always normalized to 1. Sometimes it acquires a small imaginary part due to numerical problems, but I define the ProbabilityDistribution as

```
cdist = ProbabilityDistribution[Re[pdf], {t, 0, 2}];
clist = RandomVariate[cdist, n];
```

so the imaginary part is taken care of. The second line is where the problem starts. As I said, cutting off `pdf` at some maximum value seems to help somewhat, but it's still orders of magnitude slower than on macOS.

I'm currently considering to just generate random numbers according to a uniform distribution, and subsequently mapping them to this distribution. However, I'm still interested in finding out what may cause this problem.

Comment: Is your version of Mathematica the same on both computers? Have you tried running it in the cloud, since the cloud runs the Linux version?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. I have Mathematica 10.0.2 on my Macbook, and several different versions on the linux machine, including 10.3 and 11.0. However, all the versions on the linux machine show the same problem. I have not tried running it in the cloud - let me give that a shot too.

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Otherwise it's difficult to make any statements.

Comment: Your pdf looks like two separate beta distributions but does the pdf integrate to 1 over 0 to 2?  It looks like it could integrate something larger than 1 (like maybe 2).

Comment: I added some code, but I'm not sure this is actually helpful. And @JimB, the pdfs are always normalized to 1.

Comment: Not true and not in your code.  Try `pdfFake = ProbabilityDistribution[x^2, {x, 0, 10}];
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] pdfFake]`.  You might very well need the `Method="Normalize"` option for `ProbabilityDistribution` but we can't tell until you post your code rather than a picture of the code.  Do you expect folks to type in all of that?

Comment: I meant that _my_ pdfs are normalized. Sorry, could've been clearer there. I checked by numerically integrating, they always integrate to 1 over {0,2}. I added an example of a problematic pdf to my question now.

Comment: I assume that `pdf` is set to the large expression you posted (please make this explicit) and I put `n=1`. I did not get a result with v12.0 on macOS in about one minute.

Comment: I just tried in 10.0.2 and 10.3 on macOS. 10.0 returns results quickly, but I did not test if they are correct. 10.3 is very slow. The difference you see if between versions, not Mac/Linux.

Comment: Thank you, I had no way of testing whether 10.0 would give results on Linux. The funny thing is that 9.x doesn't give results as well. What could be different in 10.0 from all other versions?

Comment: I'm curious as to why some numbers appear to be "likely" rational numbers:  80., 144., and 0.5 rather than 80, 144, and 1/2.  Is `-1.45946 + 2.91891 t` really `-ArcCos[1/9] + 2 ArcCos[1/9] t` ?  Using the exact rational numbers might help get rid of the small imaginary numbers.